# Your app is not on your GOPATH - deploying to app Engine go1.12

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-platform

i have an problem with appengine and go112.

i can´t deploy without an error to the cloud:

```
2019/09/04 14:36:10 Copying /workspace/_gopath/src/mysql to /tmp/staging/srv/gopath/src/mysql
2019/09/04 14:36:10 Your app is not on your GOPATH, this build may fail.
2019/09/04 14:36:10 Building from Go source in /tmp/staging/srv, with main package at ./...
2019/09/04 14:36:10 Building /tmp/staging/srv, saving to /tmp/staging/usr/local/bin/start
2019/09/04 14:36:11 Wrote build output to /builder/outputs/output
2019/09/04 14:36:11 Failed to build app: Your app is not on your GOPATH, please move it there and try again.
building app with command '[go build -o /tmp/staging/usr/local/bin/start ./...]', env '[PATH=/go/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/builder/google-cloud-sdk/bin/:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin HOSTNAME=89fd1b631b04 HOME=/builder/home BUILDER_OUTPUT=/builder/outputs DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive GOROOT=/usr/local/go/ GOPATH=/go GOPATH=/tmp/staging/srv/gopath]': err=exit status 1, out=go build: cannot use -o with multiple packages.
PS C:\gopath\projects\gp-sql>
```

My project is under the gopath and i tried serveral modifications of it.

[image]

output of "go env"

```
set GOPATH=C:\gopath
set GOROOT=C:\golang
```

Anybody an idea what i´m missing?

Comment: It should be under `c:\gopath` not the `c:\gopath\projects`

Comment: same problem - i think i will test it on a linux machine

Comment: fixed. wrong folder structure. didn´t have my code in the src folder in gopath.

Comment: @DavidM that's it! make it `gopath/src/helloworld` instead of `/helloworld`

Answer (score 2):

Your project folder should be in "\src", not "\projects".

For [standard Go setups](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Workspaces), whatever your basic GOPATH environment variable points to, inside that folder should be a structure like:

```
bin/
                             # command executables

src/
    github.com/golang/example/
        .git/                      # Git repository metadata
    hello/
        hello.go               # command source
    myproject1/
        main.go                # command source
        main_test.go           # test source
        app.yaml               # google cloud configuration
    myproject2/
        beepboop.go            # command source
    stringutil/
        reverse.go             # package source
        reverse_test.go        # test source
    golang.org/x/image/
        .git/                  # Git repository metadata
    bmp/
        reader.go              # package source
        writer.go              # package source
    ... (many more repositories and packages omitted) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a documented difference in the new version of go. Following this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go112/go-differences#gopath) should do the trick

If this doesn't work for you try creating a new GPATH folder, modify the Env Variable to make this folder you new gopath and put your application in the root of that folder.

Comment: tried this - same result. 
even tried to upload with linux subsystem - same error.
the error dissaper, if i remove the github libary

Comment: Ok, in order to debug this properly please share your code and setup with us or follow this [Quickstart Guide](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go112/quickstart)

Comment: Followed quickstart guide and used the demo project go111 > cloudsql. Same Error. it seems depending on the go-sql-driver github package